# Issue booting headless FreeBSD system, requires monitor to boot

Tags: boot, freebsd, headless

I'm trying to set up a headless FreeBSD 13.1 system.  I've done so
successfully before on this particular machine, but for whatever reason,
after a complete reinstall, it doesn't want to boot without a monitor
attached via HDMI.  Since it never shows up on the network, I'm assuming
it never even gets past the boot prompt.

It boots as expected if I plug in an HDMI cable to a monitor before powering up the machine.  Plugging in a monitor after unsuccessfully trying to boot
without a monitor does not work (black display).

I tried adding `-P` to `/boot.config`, but this had no effect.  The system
is, apart from that, fairly vanilla.

The system is a fan-less Chinese(?) "Basoaro" system with an American
Megatrends BIOS, but I can't find anything in the BIOS that seems
relevant, and since it *used* to be possible to boot the system without
an attached monitor, I'm assuming it's not a BIOS-related issue.

Whatever I did before to get it to boot headless, I've forgotten what it
was.

Comment: Have you tried hitting `[Enter]`? From BIOSs complaining about a clock’s battery low voltage I am used to hitting `F2`, too. Does this strange behavior you’re experiencing show with other operating systems?

Comment: @KaiBurghardt I wouldn't be able to hit any key if a keyboard was not attached (which it wouldn't be when I run the system as a headless system; which implicitly also means keyboard-less). As you can see in the answer I posted, the issue was due to the 2nd stage boot loader of the OS blocking when the console device wasn't read.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I have a couple “headless” systems with full-disk encryption (using a keyphrase) so they are (at least temporarily) equipped _with a keyboard_ when powered up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe my issue might have been solved by simply adding

```
console="efi"
```

... to `/boot/loader.conf`. The [`loader.conf(5)`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=loader.conf) manual describes this as "selecting the EFI console".
This seems not to block the boot process when there's no attached video
or serial console.

I was initially afraid of assigning a value to the `console` setting as I didn't
want to get locked out entirely with no way of accessing the system,
but I don't know whether that's even a possible risk.

Answer (score -1):

Putting `console="nullconsole"` to `loader.conf` worked for me (Geekom MiniAir 11). Kudo to Kusalananda for pointing me in the right direction!

Quote from [man `loader.conf`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?loader.conf(5)):

> `nullconsole` selects a mute console (useful for systems with neither a video console nor a serial port).